# How to use mysql query optimzer hints in Yii2?

Tags: mysql, yii2, query-hints

I've stumbled upon the `optimizer hints` MySQL feature [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/optimizer-hints.html) that I did not know existed and tried to figure out how to use this with `Yii2`.

MySQL supports setting specific options by using `optimizer hints`, e.g.:

```
SELECT /*+ NO_RANGE_OPTIMIZATION(t3 PRIMARY, f2_idx) */ f1
  FROM t3 WHERE f1 > 30 AND f1 < 33;
SELECT /*+ BKA(t1) NO_BKA(t2) */ * FROM t1 INNER JOIN t2 WHERE ...;
SELECT /*+ NO_ICP(t1, t2) */ * FROM t1 INNER JOIN t2 WHERE ...;
SELECT /*+ SEMIJOIN(FIRSTMATCH, LOOSESCAN) */ * FROM t1 ...;
EXPLAIN SELECT /*+ NO_ICP(t1) */ * FROM t1 WHERE ...;
SELECT /*+ MERGE(dt) */ * FROM (SELECT * FROM t1) AS dt;
INSERT /*+ SET_VAR(foreign_key_checks=OFF) */ INTO t2 VALUES(2);
```

Is there `Yii2` native way of setting those `query hints`?

Comment: I consider them them there as a option of last resort. Getting the indexes right ahead of time and letting the optimizer hopefully make good decisions is my preference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use second argument of [`select()`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-query#select()-detail) to pass select options:

```php
$query = (new Query())
    ->select('f1', '/*+ NO_RANGE_OPTIMIZATION(t3 PRIMARY, f2_idx) */')
    ->from('t3');
```